# How can I access keys from an array stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to access the name key of the variable `drawnCard` in this code and I cannot figure out why it does not work.

Would you mind checking out the end of my Javascript code ?

http://jsbin.com/ohinif/10/edit

Please don't mind the highly probable beginner's coding...

Thanks!!

Comment: Please put the relevant code directly into your question.

Comment: @Blazemonger : Hi Blazemonger, thanks, I will keep that in mind for the next ones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When splicing the one element out of your array, it is still returning it as an array.

Therefore to get the name you would need to use:

```
var drawnCard = deck.splice(randomCard, 1);
console.log(drawnCard[0].name) // note the index here
```

Or you could extract the first item from the splice when pulling it out like so:

```
var drawnCard = deck.splice(randomCard, 1)[0]; // and the first index here
console.log(drawnCard.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! That does it perfectly. I could swear I tried using the first method.. if so I must have done it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do this to your Code

```
var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
console.log(randomCard)
var drawnCard = deck.splice(randomCard, 1)[0];
console.log(drawnCard.name);
```

**DEMO Here**

http://jsbin.com/ohinif/17/edit

Comment: Thanks The-Val! Would you mind explaining this syntax of splice() followed by an index? I don't quite get how it reads/works.. Thanks

Comment: Ha never mind, I got it, instead of returning an array it returns its first item. So simple but only if you know it's possible :)